# How can I delegate to the first element of an array with Mouse?

Tags: perl, delegates, mouse, moose

I have an object which holds a stack of objects.  The object represents the current state, and each object in the stack holds the state at a particular level of nesting.

```
package State;

use Mouse;
use RealState;

has state_stack => {
    is    => 'rw',
    isa   => 'ArrayRef[RealState]',
    default => sub {
        return [RealState->new]
    }
};
```

I want State to delegate to `State->state_stack->[0]`.  How can I do that efficiently with *Mouse* (so no meta hacking).  I cannot use Moose, [my project](http://github.com/schwern/test-more) cannot have any dependencies (I'm bundling Mouse::Tiny).

"You can't" is fine, I'll write an `AUTOLOAD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't it directly, but there's a hack better than AUTOLOAD. That is, RealState->meta->get_all_method_names() gives you method names which are defined in RealState.

```
#!perl
use 5.14.0;
package RealState {
    use Mouse;

    sub foo { 'foo' }
    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
}
package State {
    use Mouse;

    has stack => (
        is => 'rw',
        isa => 'ArrayRef',
        default => sub { [ RealState->new ] },
    );

    # define delegates for stack->[0]
    my $meta = __PACKAGE__->meta;
    foreach my $name(RealState->meta->get_all_method_names) {
        next if Mouse::Object->can($name); # avoid 'new', 'DESTROY', etc.

        # say "delegate $name";
        $meta->add_method($name => sub {
            my $self = shift;
            $self->stack->[0]->$name(@_);
        });
    }

    $meta->make_immutable;
}

my $state = State->new();
say $state->foo();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'd be happier with something more dynamic, the other elements in the stack might be instances of a subclass with extensions.  I guess I could rerun that every time I changed the stack, doesn't happen very often.  I'd have to remove the immutable flag.  Does it need a `next if State->can($name)`?

Comment: more dynamic! If so, AUTOLOAD is a more smart way. Or, If I ware you, I'd define sub first { $state->stack->[0] } and use $stack->first->foo(), which is simple and effective.